# Marshmallow app is not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

This is my gradle file.

It is working fine under marshmallow, but in marshmallow it is not working and i did not getting any error.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.7'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any dangerious permissions declared in the manifesr only!?

Comment: Have you add runtime permissions depend on your usage like camera,Phone call?

Comment: No i didn't have any runtime permissions like camera or phone call.

Comment: Show your manifest file. Some permission can not be granted just from Manifest like those days. You have to get permissions at run time from the user!

Comment: I have permission like internet, maps ,external storage read write.

Comment: You need to implement dynamic permissions, mean while you can enable all permissions from app setting and run your app.

Comment: Yes i did, but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Starting from android 6.0 (API level 23), you will need to declare the permissions in the manifest as well as check anc request them in the runtime.

Follow this tutorial from Google:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Or you can use my library to handle them easily. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 1):

Use code like this! For example this code asks permission from user to record audio in AudioRecordFragment.

I think you have problems  with permissions. You didnt wrote what insactly your app does!

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void tryStart() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
    {
        final int checkAudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        final int checkStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (checkAudio != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                showNeedPermissionsMessage();
            } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showNeedPermissionsMessage();
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        } else {
            DoSomeThing();
        }
    } else {
            DoSomeThing();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS:
            boolean userAllowed = true;
            for (final int result : grantResults) {
                userAllowed &= result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            }
            if (userAllowed) {
                DoSomeThing();

            } else {
                showNeedPermissionsMessage();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```